# Using Thrust from Air Pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure

Alright, so I've been messing around with turning air pressure into thrust, however I'm only a sophomore in high school, so my physics knowledge is fairly limited. (I've studied higher level physics, but have nothing official.)

So, with that being said, I've been messing around with utilizing thrust from air pressure. I've got so far, that force (used as thrust) would be calculated by:

$f = pa$

where

$f =$ force

$p =$ pressure

$a =$ area

Is this the correct formula for the thrust from a gas flowing through a small hole?

Comment: 1/4 inch diameter? If so the area is only 0.05 square inches.

Comment: 0.196349541 square inches

Comment: How have you measured the force(thrust)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my issue - 1/4 diameter is only 0.1963.. square inches. I've been using the diameter for some reason..

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the thrust is related to the [exhaust velocity of the gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Specific_impulse_as_a_speed_.28effective_exhaust_velocity.29): 
$$
F_{thust}=v_e\dot{m}=\rho A{v_e}^2
$$
Assuming that the gas is expelled in to the atmosphere and not into a piston chamber, since in the second case your equation would be correct.

If the gas flow is in a steady state, you could use [Bernoulli's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) to get a good estimate for the exhaust velocity as a function of pressure, or use the slightly midfield version which also accounts for frictional losses:
$$
p_1+\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_1^2+{\rho}gz_1=p_2+\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_2^2+{\rho}gz_2+\left(f\frac{L}{D}+{\sum}K\right)\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_2^2
$$

PS: It which also be useful if you would describe your setup, so we know how you measure the thrust and velocity.